# About ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy Why not has save_all method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` class only has `delete_all` and `destroy_all` methods , I can't look at `save_all` method , but I used "build" to initialize many objects, I want to save them once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) but no `save_all`.

You can use `update_all` this way:

```
# Update all billing objects with the 3 different attributes given
Billing.update_all( "category = 'authorized', approved = 1, author = 'David'" )

# Update records that match our conditions
Billing.update_all( "author = 'David'", "title LIKE '%Rails%'" )

# Update records that match our conditions but limit it to 5 ordered by date
Billing.update_all( "author = 'David'", "title LIKE '%Rails%'",
                      :order => 'created_at', :limit => 5 )
```

If you have initialized many objects using `build`, then you can save them like this(if they all are in an array):

```
initialized_objects.each(&:save)
```